# Need Help For integrating interstitials admob on my quotes android template

Tags: java, android, xml, admob, interstitial

I have quotes android  app came with admob banner template but I don't how to integrate interstitials admob to this project. Template with database with sqlite.

Here codes for MainActivity.java

```
package com.XXXX.MYpackage;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.XXXX.MYpackage.R;
import com.XXXX.MYpackage.activity.AbstractContentActivity;
import com.XXXX.MYpackage.activity.FavouristList;
import com.XXXX.MYpackage.activity.QuoteList;
import com.XXXX.MYpackage.activity.SearchActivity;
import com.XXXX.MYpackage.activity.SettingActivity;
import com.XXXX.MYpackage.db.DataHeper;
import com.XXXX.MYpackage.db.entity.QOD;
import com.XXXX.MYpackage.utils.CustomSharePreferences;
import com.XXXX.MYpackage.utils.WriteLog;

public class MainActivity extends AbstractContentActivity{

private ImageButton btn_author;
private ImageButton btn_quotes;
private ImageButton btn_fav;
private ImageButton btn_facebook;
private ImageButton btn_search;

final static int AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE = 10;
private DataHeper dataHeper;

private TextView tv_body;
private PendingIntent mAlarmSender;


@Override
protected void initView() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.initView();
CustomSharePreferences sharePreferences = new    
CustomSharePreferences(getApplicationContext());`

btn_author = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.d_authors_btn);
btn_quotes = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.d_quotes_btn);
btn_fav = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.d_favs_btn);

tv_body = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.d_qod_body);
btn_facebook = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.actionbar_facebook_btn);
btn_search = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.actionbar_search_btn);

dataHeper = new DataHeper(getApplicationContext());
btn_author.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
WriteLog.d("ThangTB", "onclick image");
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
}
});

btn_quotes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
WriteLog.d("ThangTB", "onclick image");
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuoteList.class);
startActivity(i);
}
});

btn_fav.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
WriteLog.d("ThangTB", "onclick image");
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FavouristList.class);
startActivity(i);
}
});
btn_facebook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
facebook();
}
});

btn_search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent intentSearch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class);
startActivity(intentSearch);
}
});

mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this,
0, new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmService_Service.class), 0);
 // We want the alarm to go off 30 seconds from now.
long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

// Schedule the alarm!
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,firstTime, 30*1000, mAlarmSender);
}


@Override
protected int getViewLayoutId() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return R.layout.dashboard;
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
new GetData().execute();
super.onResume();
}


private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>{

private QOD quoteOfDay;
public GetData() {
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
quoteOfDay = dataHeper.getQOD();
return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
if (quoteOfDay!=null) {
tv_body.setText(Html.fromHtml(quoteOfDay.getBody()));
}
super.onPostExecute(result);
}
}

public void facebook() {
Uri localUri = Uri.parse(getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_fanpage));
Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", localUri);
startActivity(localIntent);

}
}
```

**Here is some xml codes from admob banner (quotepreview.xml) and others xml using same code for admob--- I think only this codes for admob banner.**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/qp_main_parent"  
    android:background="@drawable/bg_default" android:clickable="true" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/widget99"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@id/ad_holder" style="@style/AdHolder" />
    <RelativeLayout android:background="@drawable/actionbar_bg" 
    android:paddingRight="5.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="48.0dip"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">
    <com.google.ads.AdViewandroid:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="k15XXX"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,xxx2xxxx"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageViewandroid:background="@drawable/dashboard_bar_shadow"android:layout_width=
    "fill_parent"android:layout_height="6.0dip"/> 
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollViewandroid:id="@id/qp_body_wrapper"android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"android:layout_height="fill_parent"android:
    layout_marginTop="10.0dip"android:layout_above="@id/widget34"android:layout_below
    ="@id/widget99">

    <LinearLayoutandroid:orientation="vertical"android:id="@id/qp_body_
    wrapper_container"android:clickable="true"android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextViewandroid:textSize="18.0dip"android:gravity="left"android:id="@id/qp_body"
    android:padding="10.0dip"android:clickable="true"android:layout_width=
    "fill_parent"android:layout_height="wrap_content"style="@style/QuoteViewText"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayoutandroid:gravity="center"android:orientation="horizontal"android:id=
    "@id/widget34"android:layout_width="fill_parent"android:layout_height=
    "wrap_content"android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Buttonandroid:id="@id/qp_previous_btn"android:background="@drawable/
    state_left_arrow"android:layout_width="48.0dip"android:layout_height=
    "48.0dip"android:layout_margin="12.0dip"/>

    <Buttonandroid:id="@id/qp_random_btn"android:background="@drawable/state_
    refresh_btn"android:layout_width="48.0dip"android:layout_height="48.0dip"
    android:layout_margin="12.0dip"/>

    <Buttonandroid:id="@id/qp_favourite"android:background="@drawable/
    qp_fav_btn_normal"android:layout_width="48.0dip"android:layout_height=
    "48.0dip"android:layout_margin="12.0dip"/>

   <Buttonandroid:id="@id/qp_next_btn"android:background="@drawable/
   state_right_arrow"android:layout_width="48.0dip"android:layout_height=
   "48.0dip"android:layout_margin="12.0dip"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is code from AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.XXXX.MYpackage"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="7"
android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomDark" >
<activity
android:name=".SplashActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"> >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<receiver android:name="com.XXXX.MYpackage.Widget" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
android:resource="@xml/widget_generic" />
</receiver>

<service android:name="com.XXXX.MYpackage.AlarmService_Service"  
android:process=":remote" />
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".activity.AuthorList" android:screenOrientation="portrait">> 
</activity>
<activity android:name=".activity.AuthorQuoteList" 
android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".activity.QuoteView" android:screenOrientation="portrait"> 
</activity>
<activity android:name=".activity.QuoteList" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".activity.FavouristList" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".activity.CategoryList" android:screenOrientation="portrait">   
</activity>
<activity android:name=".activity.FilterList" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".activity.CategoryQuoteList" 
android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".activity.SearchActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".activity.HelpActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"> 
</activity>
<activity android:name=".activity.SettingActivity" 
android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 

android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|
screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Please help me integrate admob interstitial. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any extra layout or Manifest config to integrate interstitials, but you will need to add a small amount of code.

See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced

Comment: Where should I put code from this source (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced) ? Please give me  example ?

Comment: It goes into your MainActivity. The link above provides an exact example. Follow it.